# How to login and stay logged in with Python Requests?

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I want to log in to an API and stay logged with Python requests.

I call every API with a Bearer access_token. But when I do it, the system logs out and I do not want it.

I try to do create a login request and take an access token from it then use it in every API call but it did not work.

```
def main_function():
    username = 'i...ng.com'
    password = '2...a.'

    payload = {"grant_type": "password", "client_id": "e...3",
               "client_secret": "1..", 'username': username, 'password': password}
    url = settings.API_ADDRESS + "token"
    test = requests.post(url, data=payload)

    print(test)  # response 200
    access_key = ""

    response_dict = json.loads(test.text)
    for i in response_dict:
        if i == "access_token":
            access_key = response_dict[i]

    access_key = "Bearer " + access_key
    settings.API_TOKEN = access_key
    print(access_key) # logically true bearer access_token
    my_function(access_key)

 def my_function(access_key):
        ratio = requests.get(settings.API_ADDRESS + "analyze/scoring/" + id,
                             headers={'Authorization': access_key})
       print(ratio)print(ratio_content)
```

All login parameters are true. But it didn't work and here is the error.

error:

```
b'{"code":-1,"message":"Input string was not in a correct format.","stacktrace":"   at System.Number.ThrowOverflowOrFormatException(ParsingStatus status, TypeCode type)\\n   at System.
Number.ParseInt32(ReadOnlySpan`1 value, NumberStyles styles, NumberFormatInfo info)\\n   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)\\n   at OfficeOpenXml.Ut
ils.TypeConversion.NumericTypeConversions.<>c.<.cctor>b__3_2(Object o)\\n   at OfficeOpenXml.Utils.TypeConversion.NumericTypeConversions.TryConvert(Object obj, Object& convertedObj, Ty
pe convertToType)\\n   at OfficeOpenXml.Utils.TypeConversion.TypeConvertUtil`1.ConvertToReturnType()\\n   at OfficeOpenXml.Utils.ConvertUtil.GetTypedCellValue[T](Object value)\\n   at
Otc.Data.Services.GlobalScoringService.GetScoringData(String filePath) in /var/www/vhosts/api.myaddress.com/src/src/Otc.Data/Services/GlobalScoringService.cs:line 76\\n   at
 Otc.API.Controllers.AnalyzeController.GetScoringData(Int32 documentId) in /var/www/vhosts/api.myaddress.com/src/src/Otc.API/Controllers/AnalyzeController.cs:line 79\\n   at
 lambda_method692(Closure , Object )\\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMe
thodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)\\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(Controlle
rActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)\\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(Controll
erActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)\\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(Acti
onExecutedContextSealed context)\\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\\n   at Mi
crosoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object st
ate, Boolean isCompleted)\\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next,
 Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)\\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)\\n   at Microsoft.
AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)\\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.Authorizati
onMiddlewareResultHandler.HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)\\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Aut
horization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\\n   at Otc.API.Sta
rtup.<>c.<<Configure>b__3_2>d.MoveNext() in /var/www/vhosts/api.myaddress.com/src/src/Otc.API/Startup.cs:line 180"}'
<Response [500]>
```

Comment: have you tried using requests' session?

Comment: @Kristian I did not try. How can I do it?

Comment: I just noticed that you're using oauth2 authorization. In that case you can just save the access token and reuse the `Authorization: Bearer ey...` header

Comment: @Kristian I'm so new at this. Can you write an answer